# Reading values from dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to read tags from a selected collection of bibliographic data in ZOTERO with Javascript.

For those who aren't familiar with ZOTERO: it has an in-built "run JS" panel to work directly with items selected / marked in the standalone version.

This is the script I am using to read data from a selected folder and access the tags:

```
var s = new Zotero.Search();
s.libraryID = ZoteroPane.getSelectedLibraryID();

var itemIDs = await s.search();

for (itemID of itemIDs) {
       item = Zotero.Items.get(itemID);
       return item;
       itemTAG = item.getTags();
       return itemTAG;
    }
```

When I call `return itemIDs;` before the `for` loop, I get 4943 `key:value` pairs, which correctly mirrors the number of items in my collection.

The structure looks like this:

```
[
    "0": 21848
    "1": 21849
    "2": 21850
    "3": 21851
    "4": 21852
    "5": 21853
    "6": 21854
    "7": 21855
    "8": 21856
    "9": 21857
    "10": 21858
]
```

What I would actually like to do is iterate through all IDs to get the bibliographic data for each item and return the tags.

This is why I first tried a **for/in loop**, but this didn't work, supposedly because I wasn't calling the `key:value` pairs (corresponding to a dictionary in Python?) correctly.

However, the above **for/of** loop works at least for the first item (item "0") and returns the following data:

```
{
    "key": "BDSIJ5P4",
    "version": 1085,
    "itemType": "book",
    "place": "[Augsburg]",
    "publisher": "[Gabriel Bodenehr]",
    "date": "[circa 1730]",
    "title": "Constantinopel",
    "numPages": "1 Karte",
    "creators": [
        {
            "firstName": "Gabriel",
            "lastName": "Bodenehr",
            "creatorType": "author"
        }
    ],
    "tags": [
        {
            "tag": "Europa"
        }
    ],
    "collections": [
        "DUW2PJDP"
    ],
    "relations": {
        "dc:replaces": [
            "http://zotero.org/groups/2289797/items/ZB5J5VZK"
        ]
    },
    "dateAdded": "2019-02-13T17:27:29Z",
    "dateModified": "2020-03-23T13:13:13Z"
}
```

So my two questions are:

1. How can I create a proper for/in loop that retrieves these same data for each item?
2. How can I return tags only? It seems that `item.getTags()` [which I used in analogy to the `getNotes()` examples in the documentation] may not be a valid function. Would that be specific to Zotero or Javascript in general?

Comment: Don't put `return` inside the loop. It will exit the function on the first iteration.

Comment: if `itemIDs` is an array just map through it

Comment: I have moved both return statements out of the loop now.
´´´var s = new Zotero.Search();
s.libraryID = ZoteroPane.getSelectedLibraryID();

var itemIDs = await s.search();

for (itemID of itemIDs) {
       item = Zotero.Items.get(itemID);
       itemTAG = item.getTags();
       
    }

return itemTAG;
return item;´´´
Result is tags of one single item. Will try and fix the for/in loop.

Comment: If the code in second block is verbatim,  then it appears to be syntactically corrupt.  `[ ]` is an array.  Each key/value pair has a `:` which is indicative of being inside an object literal `{ }`. Moreover, each key/value pair should be delimited with a `,` whether they are wrapped in `{ }` or not. At best it appears to be one badly formatted string within an array.

Comment: Yes, the second block was verbatim, I just took out a few hundred pairs between the squared brackets. It did look odd to me, too, but I am not very familiar with data structures in JS. Interestingly, though, the `map()` function suggested by @Barmar below worked. I get tags only for all items now, but still wrapped in some kind of array.

Comment: @zer00ne I think she's showing how the console shows the array, not a JavaScript literal in code.

Comment: Exactly, this is coming from the *return value* console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map()` to call a function on every array element and return an array of all the results.

```
return itemIDs.map(itemID => Zotero.Items.get(itemID).getTags())
```

Comment: Thanks, the results look much better now: `[
    "0": [
        "0": {
            "tag": "Europa"
        }
    ]
    "1": [
        "0": {
            "tag": "Europa"
        }
    ]
    "2": [
        "0": {
            "tag": "Europa"
        }
    ]
    "3": [
        "0": {
            "tag": "Russia"
        }
        "1": {
            "tag": "Europa"
        }
    ]
]`